# Limit access to specific websites by time and usage

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, traffic-shaping

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, I can't find it. Pointers appreciated if so.

I want to set up my home network so that access to some sites (e.g. YouTube, Facebook) is restricted:

- By device, i.e. Set different rules for different devices.
- By time: Set times in the day when access is permitted, and others when it's not.
- By usage: So that a particular device can only use a defined capacity per site per day.

The goal is to set some limits for children(*). So, for example, each child can only access a specific site (e.g. youtube) at certain times of the day; and that there's a daily usage cap on how much they can watch.  Each has their own wireless device, hence the desire to set restrictions separately for each device.

We have a single ADSL broadband connection with currently 2 wireless routers, none of which offer any traffic shaping. I would be open to changing any of the hardware (UK based). Also interested in any software-based solutions (there are a couple of computers around that could be put to use if appropriate, e.g. an old Mac PPC running OpenBSD).

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

*Yes, I know that supervising children is the best approach. And that limiting access doesn't prevent them being exposed to inappropriate content. The technical question is part of the story, not the whole solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what provider you have I suggest you open the web browser and type the IP address of the router (default is 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1). Log in using the default username admin and default password admin, if that doesn't work try only typing admin in username and log in without typing password. Then depending on your provider you have a menu where you can choose a bunch of stuff, here you can also block websites and the other things you're looking for.

See these links for more help:

[How to block a website using your router](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q58xIadzOFo)

[How to set up access control for website blocking](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-273.html)
- This one is for a TP-Link wireless router but it's pretty much the same no matter what provider you have

Hope that helped! If you still need help, I would recommend you to give some information on what router and provider you're using.